# CSS vs. Javascript (or library js) for DropDown Menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am about to start a project that will require dropdown menus - Basically, it will consist of categories and within those categories - there will be an additional dropdown for subcategories. ALA.

```
MENU
---> Colors
---> Sizes --> Large
---> Makes     Medium
```

each of the cats "could" have a submenu.

My question is about the advent of the CSS3 only menus - and what advantages if any do they have over conventional JS created ones. I know there are a bunch of jQuery menus as well as CSS3 -- I am curious, which is the more robust/maintanable solution now?

CSS3 vs. jQuery( or any js solution) for menu creation?

Comment: Oh, look: [a *discussion*](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: @Titanium exactly! on IE7 works so fast you cannot even see it!

Comment: "and what advantages if any do they have over conventional JS created ones" — Not an advantage: They make it really hard to build them in an accessible way.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can create drop down menus without using any CSS3 specific attributes.
2. Unless you need something animated or that actually requires jQuery or javascript then stick with CSS.

Why?

It is possible, although unlikely, that your user has javascript turned off on their browser meaning they won't see your menu the way it's intended, there is no way for a normal user to disable CSS (yes it can be done with web developer add ons). You're also including an entire library and scripting for something that just doesn't require it.

What you explained doesn't require jQuery or javascript at all so why bother using it?